# react prop not rendering in parent component and even in the same one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote some dummy code in React using two components.

First one:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Square from "./components/square";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Square color={this.props.CardStyle} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Second one:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Square extends Component {
  render() {
    var CardStyle = {
      height: "200px",
      width: "150px",
      padding: 0,
      backgroundColor: "#FFF",
      filter: "drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #666)"
    };

    const mera = "merone";

    return (
      <div style={CardStyle}>
        <p>{this.props.mera}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Square;
```

Now, I would like to render on the p of the Square component its prop "mera", but it does not. Also, I would like to render that passing it to the parent component, App. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your confusion lies in how to use react props. ([Props and components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)) A prop in react is simply a variable that is passed from the parent to the child. In this case you are looking for a prop 'mera' in your child component 'Square' however you are not passing that down from the parent. If you want to set the value from within your child component you should probably use react state. Otherwise you would pass it down using:

```
<Square mera={"merone"} color={this.props.CardStyle} />
```

There are multiple ways to use variables in React.

Props (make sure to pass down the variable):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Square extends Component {
  render() {
    var CardStyle = {
      height: "200px",
      width: "150px",
      padding: 0,
      backgroundColor: "#FFF",
      filter: "drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #666)"
    };

    return (
      <div style={CardStyle}>
        <p>{this.props.mera}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Square;
```

State:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Square extends Component {

  state = { mera: "merone" };

  render() {
    var CardStyle = {
      height: "200px",
      width: "150px",
      padding: 0,
      backgroundColor: "#FFF",
      filter: "drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #666)"
    };

    return (
      <div style={CardStyle}>
        <p>{this.state.mera}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Square;
```

Scoped variables:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Square extends Component {
  render() {
    var CardStyle = {
      height: "200px",
      width: "150px",
      padding: 0,
      backgroundColor: "#FFF",
      filter: "drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #666)"
    };

    const mera = "merone";

    return (
      <div style={CardStyle}>
        <p>{mera}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Square;
```

Class properties (WILL NOT rerender the component when modified):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Square extends Component {

  mera = "merone";

  render() {
    var CardStyle = {
      height: "200px",
      width: "150px",
      padding: 0,
      backgroundColor: "#FFF",
      filter: "drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px #666)"
    };

    return (
      <div style={CardStyle}>
        <p>{this.mera}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Square;
```

Comment: So basically I cannot reference and render internal objects different from state, right? For instance, how could I render in the Square component the const mera without transforming it into the state or without passing it into the App component and calling it with props?

Comment: Using standard JavaScript variables is totally valid. Within your Square component you could do `<p>{mera}<p>` rather than using this.props.mera. However modifying this variable after render would not update the DOM. That's where state comes in.

Comment: and, related to this: I can create objects only within the render method. I cannot create const mera outside of it. But when it comes to create a new method, for example dummyMethod = () => {....} I can do it anywhere within the component scope. why?

Comment: You can create anything outside of the render scope however it would then be enclosed by "this". If you created a property "mera" outside of a function scope you could then access it using `this.mera` in any of your functions. [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Please remember that modifying this variable WILL NOT cause a component rerender unless you define it as part of this.state

Comment: Also if you create your variable in the class fieald do not use `const`. Then as @NickAbbott said reach it via `this` in this class component. In a functional component there is no `this` for this situation. In your dummyFunction there is no `const` as you gave as an example. In a regular function there is no `function` either.

Comment: Also, I think rather explaining all of this in the comments it might be good expanding the answer :)

Comment: ok but then, promess, last question :), how should I create a new variable/object? it does not accept const nor var nor let

Comment: Do it without anything, just name it.

Answer (score 4):

`mera` is not a prop, it's a `const` in `Square`. Move `const mera = "merone"` to your `App` component, and pass it in as a prop `<Square mera={mera} .../>`

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just for fun. Accepted answer explaining some useful things like state. If your component's render depends on a changing data, then use it in your state. For other static things of course you can use class properties or variables in your render method.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  outsideRender = "outside of render as a class property";
  render() {
  const insideRender = "inside of render as a constant";
    return (
      <Child
      outsideRender={this.outsideRender}
      insideRender={insideRender}
      />
    )
  }

}


class Child extends React.Component {
  childOutsideRender = "Child's class property outside render";
  render() {
  const childInsideRender = "Child's variable inside render";
    return (
      <div>
      outsideRender: I am coming from parent, as prop and {this.props.outsideRender}
      <br />
      insideRender: I am coming from parent, as a prop and  {this.props.insideRender}
      <br />
      childOutsideRender: {this.childOutsideRender}
      <br />
      childInsideRender: {childInsideRender}
      </div>
    )
  }

}




ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```